Does buying a pet contribute to GDP?
So for example, say a cat is bought for 1000 dollars and thousand cats are bought. Does that mean the GDP goes up by million. Is the cat a used product or are pets bought not counted in GDP?

Line 92 in https://fred.stlouisfed.org/release/tables?rid=53&eid=44686#snid=44778 if you are in the US.

If that cat is sold in a pet store (i.e. it's a recorded market transaction) then it does increase GDP. It is counted as private consumption in that case.
